# ProgressDialog is not showing

Tags: java, android, android-query, aquery

I am using the AndroidQuery's way of handling images in saving then to sd card. But the dialog is not showing for some reason. The images are properly saved in sd card, only the dialog is the problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dip" 
    >

    <ProgressBar                
        android:layout_width="15dip"       
        android:layout_height="15dip"
        android:id="@+id/progress" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"       
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
        android:layout_height="75dip"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
String url = path;
File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File target = new File(ext, "Folder/Folder/" + pathName + ".jpg");

laQuery.progress(R.id.progress).download(url, target, new AjaxCallback<File>() {

    public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {

        if (file != null) {

            // Log.d("File:" + file.length() + ":" + file, status);
            Log.i("Aquery not null", "File:" + file.length());
            Log.i("Aquery not null", "File:" + file);
            Log.i("Aquery not null", "File:" + status);
        } else {
            Log.d("Failed", "" + status);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Try to hide the imageView and see if the progress bar is placed inside the relative layout correctly.

Comment: @Seraphim  I deleted the image and still no dialog shown.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RelativeLayout` children are drawn in the order they are declared in. So your `ProgressBar` is underneath the `ImageView` and Android Query doesn't have a reference to the `ImageView` to control its visibility.

Switch the order of their declarations to make the progress bar be on top.

---

Update: Checked the [source](https://github.com/androidquery/androidquery/blob/master/src/com/androidquery/AbstractAQuery.java) and `download()` requests don't support the progress bar, only `image()` requests do. You'll have to set the progress bar to visible yourself and hide it in `callback()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I deleted the image to make sure and still the dialog is not showing. as it should be.